When the biggest ellipse inscribed into symmetric trapezium touches 3 sides and when 4 sides of trapezium?
Ellipse $O$ is the biggest possible ellipse inscribed symmetrically into symmetric trapezium $ABCD$ (axis of symmetry of ellipse coincides with axis of symmetry of trapezium). When ellipse $O$ touches all sides of trapezium as in $picture 1$ and when it touches just three sides as in $picture 2$?


@RossMillikan Actually no. There are infinitely many ellipses that touch those 3 sides. (Not unique like your comment implies.) The "tallest" ellipse will be the one touching side $BC$. However, it might not necessarily be the largest (by area?), because the width is reduced.

@CalvinLin: yes, largest by area

To answer this question, we prove first auxiliary lemma:
Given isosceles triangle $ABC$ ($picture 1$ below), where $AB = CB$ and $E,F,D$ points of touching for inner circle $O$ of triangle $ABC$ with its sides, ratio of circle $O$ area to $ABC$ area as a function of ratio $FB:FC$ is continues, monotonically increasing when $FB:FC < 1$, has maximum at $FB:FC = 1$, and monotonically decreasing when $FB:FC < 1$
Let $FB:FC = x$ and $CF = CD = AD = AE = 1$; $FB = EB = x$;
It follows by Heron’s formula for area of triangle $ABC$ denoted $A$:
$A^2 = (2+x)*(2+x-2)*(2+x-1-x)*(2+x-1-x) = (2+x)*x$
We also have for area $A$ as a doubled sum of areas of triangles $AOE, EOB, CFO$, when denoting radius of inner circle as $r$:
$A = 2*(1*r)*(1*r)*(x*r)$
Combining two expressions for $A$ above, we obtain the following expression for square of ratio of area of circle $O$ to area $A$:
$(\frac{area O}{area A})^2 = \frac{\pi^2*x}{(2+x)^3}$
Derivative of $(\frac{area O}{area A})^2$:
$\frac{\pi^2*(1-x)}{(2+x)^4}$
This proves that square of ratio $area O / area A$ and thus ratio itself monotonically growing when $FB:FC < 1$, has maximum at $FB:FC = 1$, and monotonically decreasing when $FB:FC < 1$ ∎

Assume that in symmetric trapezium on $picture 2$, the biggest possible symmetrically inscribed ellipse $O$ touches only 3 sides, not touching side $BC$, touches $AB$ and $CD$ in points $F, G$, and lines $AB$ and $DC$ intersect at point $E$.
Transform ellipse and triangle $ADE$ by linear transform such that image of $O$ is inner circle $O$ of isosceles $ADE$ after transform. Ratios at which points $F, G$ divide $AE, DE$ stay the same, interval $BC$ will not touch circle $O$, and circle $O$ must be the biggest possible circle inscribed into trapezium $ABCD$ after transform (as ellipse $O$ was the biggest ellipse inscribed into trapezium $ABCD$ before transform). If Ratio $FE:FA$ is not $1$, we can slightly increase or decrease eccentricity of ellipse $O$ so that this ratio is more close to $1$ and at the same time modified ellipse $O$ is still not touching side $BC$, according to lemma above, this slightly modified ellipse will be transformed into inner circle of $ADE$ that has bigger ratio of its area to area of triangle $ADE$ and consequently bigger ratio of its area to area of trapezium $ABCD$, which is contradiction, because ellipse $O$ was assumed to be biggest before modification, this proves that ratio $FE:FA$ must be $1$ and the biggest symmetrically placed ellipse inscribed in symmetric trapezium while not touching smallest of the two parallel sides must be Steiner ellipse of triangle formed by continuation of not parallel sides of trapezium till their intersection.
